# Element search by path with attribute name and Replace values in xml using Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

How can i give complete path with attribute value to element and replace element value in xml using Python

For example: I have xml file like this:

```
 <bw>
        <bwprocesses>
                <bwprocess name="Business_Processes/Source_Processes/Receive Batch Message.process">
                    <starter>Receive Batch Message</starter>
                </bwprocess>
                <bwprocess name="Business_Processes/Source_Processes/Type Subscriber.process">
                    <starter>Receive Trade Message</starter>
                </bwprocess>
                <bwprocess name="Business_Processes/Source_Processes/Message Router.process">
                    <starter>Message JMS Queue Receiver</starter>
                </bwprocess>
        </bwprocesses>
</bw>
```

and want to update xml by giving complete element path(with attribute value) which needs to be updated.

**input : bwprocesses/ bwprocess [Business_Processes/Source_Processes/Receive Batch Message.process]/starter = new massage (new value should be updated in place of 'Receive Batch Message' in .xml)**

I tried search example using xml.etree.ElementTree but couldn't find any useful info.Tried below code to search element but getting error .Please help on it.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('a.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for e in root.findall('bwprocesses/bwprocess[@name='Business_Processes/Source_Processes/Receive Batch Message.process']/starter'):
    print e.text
```

Comment: Hi! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet. Please, read the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section to improve your question

Comment: I have added code to search the element . Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xml = '''<bw>
        <bwprocesses>
                <bwprocess name="Business_Processes/Source_Processes/Receive Batch Message.process">
                    <starter>Receive Batch Message</starter>
                </bwprocess>
                <bwprocess name="Business_Processes/Source_Processes/Type Subscriber.process">
                    <starter>Receive Trade Message</starter>
                </bwprocess>
                <bwprocess name="Business_Processes/Source_Processes/Message Router.process">
                    <starter>Message JMS Queue Receiver</starter>
                </bwprocess>
        </bwprocesses>
</bw>'''
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
for e in root.findall("bwprocesses/bwprocess[@name='Business_Processes/Source_Processes/Receive Batch Message.process']/starter"):
    print('Before: {}'.format(e.text))
    e.text = 'Any text you want'

for e in root.findall("bwprocesses/bwprocess[@name='Business_Processes/Source_Processes/Receive Batch Message.process']/starter"):
    print('After: {}'.format(e.text))
```

Comment: Getting error in for e in root.findall("bwprocesses/bwprocess[@name='Business_Processes/Source_Processes/Receive Batch Message.process']/starter"):
    "expected path separator (%s)" % (op or tag)
SyntaxError: expected path separator ([)

Comment: Thanks a lot...Yes, it is working in python3, I have python version 2.6.

Comment: So you better move to python 3 ASAP. If it works for you, feel free to vote up.